# Apache proxy to subdomain (vhost)

Tags: apache-2.2, php, proxy, subdomain

I need to proxy to a webserver were I don't have control over it. The problem is that the webserver hosts more than 1 domain and subdomains on the same IP. This means that when I use apache proxy I will see the default apache page. Not the specifig vhost page of the subdomain. I need to see the current subdomain which I suppose is in a Vhost ( the same effect as browsing to it)

This is what iam currently using

ProxyPreserveHost On

```
ProxyPass / http://sub.myweb.com:80/
ProxyPassReverse / http://sub.myweb.com:80/

ServerName localhost
```

But when I do this this will just show the standard apache is working page. Not the subdomain page.

Hope you guys can help me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ProxyPreserveHost Directive

When enabled, this option will pass the Host: line from the incoming request to the proxied host, instead of the hostname specified in the ProxyPass line.

This option should normally be turned Off. It is mostly useful in special configurations like proxied mass name-based virtual hosting, where the original Host header needs to be evaluated by the backend server.

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_proxy.html

Maybe you should leave it turned off?

Comment: Thanks, I copied my settings from Digtalocean and I just ovread the preserve host part. Happens sometimes!